# magento create a list of wishlists

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to see how many people created a wishlist, and what items (or how many in total) there are in all individual wishlists. I know how to get to an individual wishlist (by customer), but would like to know if there is a way to view / access a 'list of wishlists' preferable through php.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean wishlist like amazon, there you can create your own no.of wishlist, is am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Wishlist_Collection`, so to get a list of wishlist, just load the collection:

```
$wishlistCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/wishlist_collection');
```

Comment: Is possible allow customer can create their own no.of wishlist like amazon.

Comment: @Rathinam not out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Magento gives You only 1 wishlist so I guess You are asking about some module?

Comment: no, just trying to figure out if there is a way to see how many people create a wishlist, and then maybe what items they put in their wishlist. We are trying to determine if it's worth keeping the wishlist up or not.

Comment: You can try to examine `wishlist` table count which contains 1 row per 1 customer wishlist.

Comment: Oh that worked! I got a list of customer id's by doing:$tableName = $resource->getTableName('wishlist'); $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT wishlist_id, customer_id, sharing_code, updated_at FROM ' . $tableName.' WHERE updated_at > 0';$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);